# Opencl atomic function performance

Tags: opencl

I understand atomic functions in opencl will slow down the program significantly. This is definitely true if there IS racing when you do the writing operation into the memory.

I am curious if there IS_NOT racing, what would happen if I still use the atomic function when updating the memory? According to my understand, It will give slow down anyway since the threads are forced to executed one after one. Am I right about this?

Comment: Are you asking that atomic operations can be used as a global synchronization point or not?

Comment: If there is not racing there is no need for atomics in the first place. Using them will make the hardware put in place checks that are not needed slowing down the memory access. Even though, no threads will block due to serial access to the memory.

Comment: @VeronikaPrüssels  Yes, that's pointless. I am interested in the time spending of the atomic function.

Comment: @DarkZeros So it did slow down a bit, even if the no racing happens?

Comment: If you replace "racing" with "heavy contention" then atomics may be reasonable. The case where they are not reasonable is when every thread is trying to access the same data using atomics -- this effectively serializes the access, which is a major performance hit. If however the atomic accesses are spread across a large number of locations, or only a few threads do atomic accesses, they can work quite well. If your locations are data-dependent you still might have slow edge cases (e.g., a histogram with varied data might be fast but with identical data would be slow).